# Exercise App using Video and iPod Music integration

Tags: xcode, ipod

I am working on creating a exercise app which has about an hour long video and has a few intermittent audio instructions. I have included iPod Music in it. I want the iPod music to duck (reduce in volume) when there is audio(instruction) in the video, and go back up when the instruction is done. Looked at otherMixableAudioShouldDuck, but it seems not to work, as it is a complete one hour video and the audio is within the Video. Looked at getting the audio in separate audio files, but thats causing issues in seeking. Any fresh approach, or any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to put in your thoughts and suggestions, thanks a ton!